# On Joomla set up cannot connect to MSSQL due to user name error

Tags: php, sql-server, joomla

I installed mssql and it shows enaabled in phpinfo(). But when setting up joomla on database config page when I choose mssql and try to connect the following error comes up

> Could not connect to the database. Connector returned number: Database sqlsrv_connect failed, Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1] => 18456 [code] => 18456 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'user'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'user'. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1] => 18456 [code] => 18456 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'user'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'user'. ) )

Tried putting user root Admin but does not work. How can I get this page working?

Comment: No need to get rude. What´s your problem? Isn´t it solved on the duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, this problem happens when MSSQL server authentication is not enabled in the local server. You can enable that the following way:

- Go to MSSQL and then right click
- Click on "Properties" and then on "Security"
- Click on "Server Authentication"
- Enable Authentication Mode